# I have two list of strings, and want to link them together in this way:

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python and are currently stuck at a project.

To be more specific. I have two list of strings, and want them to link in the following way:

```
list1 = ["P1", "P2", "P3" ]

list2 = ["1", "2","3" ]
```

but, I want this

```
P1 = 1

P2 = 2
```

etc.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Create `dictionary` by `zip`:

```
d = dict(zip(list1,list2))
print (d)
{'P3': '3', 'P2': '2', 'P1': '1'}

#select by keys
print (d['P1'])
1

print (d['P2'])
2
```